# Program for universal enveloping Lie algebra Su(3) in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

From information in internet, particular this link:  http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Nov/msg00213.html

It was interseting problem of " How to do Lie algebra in Mathematica".
Now,our my small seminar(project) we have been problem `Poincaré–Birkhoff–Witt theorem and apply to calculus universal enveloping lie algebra sl(3)`. My teacher asked us to write program in `Mathematica` to calculus cofficient and ingredient of 2 monomial of su(3) .Example :

`Product of x^15*y^10*z^7 and x^4*y^5*z^6
Reamark: x,y,z be generate of universl enveloping algebra su(3) i.e:
lie bracket[x,z]=2x , [y,z]= -2y and  [x,y]=z.`

I just know this is very important problem for quantum mechanics and actually we are stuck at the moment, we have no ideal solve this problem. I feel in mathematica NonCommutativeMultiply function be very rudimentary. 
Hope you could suggest or help us.